# Why do we need 'WHERE EXISTS' operator in SQL?

Tags: sql

I found  [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) about SQL EXISTS Operator. And I am trying to understand why do we need it.
It is always possible to replace 'EXISTS' by another expression (showed below)

As an example, this SQL:

```
SELECT count(SupplierName)
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE SupplierId = Suppliers.supplierId AND Price < 20);
```

Could be replaced to this SQL:

```
SELECT count(SupplierName)
FROM Suppliers
WHERE  (SELECT count(*) FROM Products WHERE SupplierId = Suppliers.supplierId AND Price < 20) > 0;
```

I tested it, and got the same result.

Is there any situations when we have to use 'EXISTS' ?

Comment: The advantage of `exists` is that the actual count from the subquery is not needed: It only takes a *single* match to qualify. Unless the optimizer is really smart, materializing those counts is thing to slow everything down. I think you'll also find that it matches up better with standard mathematical logic.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your example, `EXISTS` is more efficient.  The subquery needs to read *all* matching rows in order to do the count.

`EXISTS`, by contract, can (and does!) stop at the first matching row.

You could argue that the SQL engine could identify this situation.  However, that would be very, very difficult for more complex queries.

In contrast to your viewpoint, I find `EXISTS` to be *more* useful than `IN` or correlated subqueries with aggregations.  It is the *preferred* method for expressing this logic.

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS is better when it comes to performance, since it needs to retrieve only a single row rather than enumerating all of them.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Exist could have better performance in some cases. 
For example to execute a query below, engine has to count all the rows in sub-query:

```
SELECT count(SupplierName)
FROM Suppliers
WHERE  (SELECT count(*) FROM Products WHERE SupplierId = Suppliers.supplierId AND Price < 20) > 0;
```

In this case it will yield, when first  Products is found;

```
SELECT count(SupplierName)
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE SupplierId = Suppliers.supplierId AND Price < 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases,`EXISTS()` is also more *expressive*. Try, for instance, to rewite the below fragment into a `NOT COUNT(*) > 0` version. Which one is more readable?

---

```
        --
        -- All the possible moves for the current board.
        -- ,which is := all the (empty spots * all the numbers  1-9)
        -- for which the same number does not occur yet in the same {row/col/box}.
        --
CREATE VIEW valid_moves AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT su.iii AS iii
                , su.yyy AS yyy
                , su.xxx AS xxx
                , su.box AS box
                , su.y3 AS y3
                , su.x3 AS x3
                , su.z3 AS z3
                , nn.val AS val
        FROM v_sudoku su            -- current board, including filled-in numbers
        CROSS JOIN all_numbers nn   -- Cartesian product here ...
        WHERE su.val IS NULL        -- empty spots
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_sudoku ny
                WHERE ny.yyy = su.yyy AND ny.val = nn.val
                )
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_sudoku nx
                WHERE nx.xxx = su.xxx AND nx.val = nn.val
                )
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_sudoku nz
                WHERE nz.box = su.box AND nz.val = nn.val
                )
        );
```